# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: Appointment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes, mass-assignment

I'm trying to create a listing object and an appointment object after an order has been successfully placed. The appointment object is nested within the Listing object if the user specifically orders an appointment with their listing. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ListingsController#update
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: appointment
```

Orders Create action:

```
def create
@order = current_cart.build_order(params[:order])
@order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
@order.user_id = current_user.id


respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save_with_payment

    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)         
    Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
    session[:cart_id] = nil

    @order.line_items.each do |line_item|
      if line_item.service_id == 2
        listing = Listing.create!(:order_id => @order.id, :user_id => current_user.id, :house_id => @order.house_id)
      end

      if line_item.service_id ==3
        Appointment.create!(:order_id => @order.id, :user_id => current_user.id, :house_id => @order.house_id, :listing_id => listing)
      end
    end

    format.html { render :action => "success", :notice => 'Thank you for your order.' }
    format.xml { render :xml => @order, :status => :created, :location => @order }

  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml { render :xml => @order.errors,
    :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Success action contains the following form:

```
<div class="contain">
<h3>Your order has been received</h3>

<% @order.line_items.each do |line_item| %> 
    <%if line_item.service_id == 2 %>
        <p>Prepare Listing</p>      
        <%= simple_form_for(@order.listing) do |f| %>
            <%= f.error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">

              <%= f.input :start_date %>
              <%= f.input :end_date %>
              <%= f.input :list_price %> <h3>Suggessted list price:****</h3>
              <%= f.input :description %>
              <%= f.input :showing_instructions %>
            </div>


            <% @order.line_items.each do |line_item2| %>
                <%if line_item2.service_id == 3 %>
                    <p>Set up appointments</p>

                    <%= f.simple_fields_for @order.appointment do |a| %>
                        <div class="form-inputs">
                            <%= a.input :start_date %>
                            <%= a.input :showing_instructions%>                         

                            <%= a.input :status %>
                         </div>
                    <% end %>                                             
                <%end%>
            <%end%>

            <div class="form-actions">
              <%= f.button :submit %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

ListingModel

```
attr_accessible :description, :end_date, :house_id, :order_id, :user_id, :appointments_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment


  has_one :appointment 
  belongs_to :order
```

AppointmentModel

```
  attr_accessible :start_date, :end_date, :listing_id, :order_id, :user_id, 

  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :user
```

OrderModel

```
  attr_accessible :first_name, :ip_address, :last_name, :cart_id  

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :house
  belongs_to :cart

  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"
  has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :listing
  has_one :appointment
```

Listings controller Update action:

```
 def update
@listing = Listing.find(params[:id])


respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.update_attributes(params[:listing])

    format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: "edit" }
    format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your `Listing` model with this

```
attr_accessible :description, :end_date, :house_id, :order_id, :user_id, :appointment_attributes
accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment
```

Comment: I still get the same error. any idea What else may be causing the issue?

Comment: Please, add update action of your listings controller (error should be there).

Comment: Updated @Nick. Am I missing something?